# Force link to open in current window/tab

Tags: html, target

I'm stumped as to the cause of this problem. The page http://capitalhedges.scot/mixpacks.php opens all links in a new tab, even if I use target="_blank" or target="_top". None of the other pages on the site does this, so it's not a case of a base target overriding (it's template driven). I've searched all over and found nothing about this problem.

I forget to mention that the links in question are when you click on an image in the pack list (click on jump to pack list or scroll down to reach them). The navbar works just how I want it to.

Comment: They're all opening in the same tab for me, except for the Facebook link.

Comment: Most browsers control how links are opened.

Comment: They're opening in the same window for me as well. Have you double checked your site in other browsers/devices?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, the problematic links are the ones in the pack list, not the navbar

Comment: "Pack list" links open in the same window/tab for me (Chrome 41, Safari 7, Firefox 36). With which browser are you experiencing the problem? Have you tried `target="_self"` or no target at all?

Comment: That's really odd. I'm using Chrome mostly (v.41 running on Ubuntu 12.04), but now I've tried this page in Firefox it's fine. This is despite the fact that the links do have 'target="_top"' - I've already tried 'target="_self"' with the same result. But never mind, as it works on your Chrome, I guess this is not going to affect a lot of people. Ubuntu is an acquired taste. Thanks for your help. :)